# moving from single webapp to multiple webapps connecting to same database

Tags: java, mysql, database, tomcat7, connection-pooling

I have a JAVA webapp which is using DB connection pooling for Tomcat+MySQL config.

I have another JAVA webapp which i want to deploy in the same Tomcat and connect to same MySQL database (even access the data from same tables).

I havent figured out a way how to achieve the same.

Should I have connection pooling context.xml for each of the webapps?
Or should I have a global configuration.

In the first case , I assume there is nothing different that i need to do. Only to deploy the webapp which has its own context.xml.. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

If having a global config is a better solution, how to achieve that. Haven't found any good tutorials about it. What changes in each of webapps need to made , so that it knows that it needs to read the global config.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with having a separate context for each webapp unless you want to centrally manage changes to the database (i.e. migrate it to a different DB, change connection parameters). If you think your connection properties will change or you want that flexibility then you can use a JNDI datasource in tomcat and manage it there (google is your friend for that).